# Apatana 3.0.7 Code Assist - Auto Complete

Tags: autocomplete, aptana, content-assist, code-assist

Hey I'm a Cisco guy,

Just started with apatana to design a web page for my small business. My question is about the code assist and the auto complete feature. Apatana is very good at picking up what i'm typing be it an element, selector or even value sometimes. The issue im having is when i begin entering text. The code assist window will pop up, and present a list of possible choices based on what i have entered so far. then i have to either stop what i'm doing and press the down arrow, or grab my mouse and select my choice for assist. Or, i can continue typing out the element (or whatever) to narrow down the list. What I'm hoping is that, there exists a feature like in cisco terminal. where you can press the "tab" key to goto the next branch point of ambigious choices. 
    Let's say I was looking for the background-color selector. In my ideal world with code assist it would go something like this.

```
"b" ->[tab]

"back" ->"g"

"backg" ->[tab]

"background" ->"-co"

"background-co" ->[enter]

"background-color:"
```

I hope this makes sense. Thank you for reading.

Moved to http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4251

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not currently available, but it's an interesting idea. I'd suggest filing a feature request at http://jira.appcelerator.org